# How can I print using map an array of arrays with objects within array react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, multidimensional-array, bootstrap-4

I have functional component that takes an array of arrays with objects but I don't know how to access data in the return function of the render

```js
let dataItems = [
  [
    {
      data1: "1234",
      data2: "ABCD",
      data3: "5678",
      data4: "EFGH",
    },
    {
      data1: "10203040",
      data2: "A1B1C1D1",
      data3: "50607080",
      data4: "EFGH",
    },
    {
      data1: "6789",
      data2: "jklm",
      data3: "1000",
      data4: "EFGH",
    },
    {
      data1: "128",
      data2: "zwxy",
      data3: "5",
      data4: "lmno",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      data1: "1234",
      data2: "ABCD",
      data3: "5678",
      data4: "EFGH",
    },
    {
      data1: "10203040",
      data2: "A1B1C1D1",
      data3: "50607080",
      data4: "EFGH",
    },
    {
      data1: "6789",
      data2: "jklm",
      data3: "1000",
      data4: "EFGH",
    },
    {
      data1: "128",
      data2: "zwxy",
      data3: "5",
      data4: "lmno",
    },
  ],
];
```

I tried to pass the data to another component to print the data but I don't know how to pass an unnamed array with the map function.

My code.

```
 dataItems.map((item, index) => {
  return ( 

{ item.content.map((c, i) =>
   <PrintComponent>
   )
    }

)
   })
```

I will print a bi-dimensional matrix in chunks of 4 elements using bootstrap 4 tabs

Im trying to show the data like a bi-dimensional array like this

| row1 | row2 | row3 | row4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data01 | data02 | data03 | data04 |
| data05 | data06 | data07 | data08 |

...

Comment: What do you want to do with the data once you're iterating it correctly? How is it to be used?

Comment: What is `<PrintComponent>`? Do you want to display this in an actual `<table>` or in some other way?

Comment: No, with tables I can make it. I need to make a row with 4 elements using collapse data (printComponent create this) but im too used to solve with incremental loop like for, while but with functional component i cant use this loops. I create the table to show how i can divide the array of arrays with objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this you have to use multiple maps for data rending.

**For Example:**

```
dataItems.map((item) => {
return item.map((items) => { console.log("data1", items.data1)});
});
```

Comment: `console.log()`? OP wants to render JSX

Comment: @Phil I'm dropping the concept for him.

Comment: Render with other component, i didn't know to pass in a nested map the value one by one of the objects, I tried like normal javascript with a double for, but jsx didn' let me. Using return item.map((items) => { <printComponent  data = {items}}); should work

Answer (score 0):

I solved with make the component within the maps.

using this lines

```
dataItems.map((item) => {
return item.map((items) => { console.log("data1", items.data1)});
});
```

gives me the data several times, so I include some slice for only one time

```
dataItems.slice(0, 1).map((item) => {
return item.map((items) => { console.log(items)});
});
```